# Gcloud sql instances create error with --database-version=MYSQL_5_7

Tags: google-cloud-sql, gcloud

How to create a MySQL 5.7 cloud sql instance with the gcloud utility?

I can create a 5.7 instance using the GCloud (web) console on my project but tt doesn't work when I use the gcloud cli command using the dedicated option : " --database-version=MYSQL_5_7"
(it's OK with the value MYSQL_5_6 that is also the default)

```
gcloud sql instances create test57euw1b --tier=D0 --database-version=MYSQL_5_7 --gce-zone=europe-west1-b
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.instances.create) HTTPError 400: Invalid instance property.
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 1.16.04 ad here my Gcloud CLI version :
$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 165.0.0
alpha 2017.03.24
beta 2017.03.24
bq 2.0.25
core 2017.07.28
gcloud 
gsutil 4.27
kubectl

The same happens usin "beta":
gcloud beta sql instances create test5757 --tier=D0 --database-version=MYSQL_5_7 --gce-zone=europe-west1-b

I'd like to be able to create a 5.7 instance with gcloud to script it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that `D0` is a first generation tier. First generation does not support MySQL 5.7 (5.5. and 5.6 only).

Please try with something like `--tier=db-n1-standard-2`.

Comment: Yes that's the right. The tier I did use a 1st gen model but 5.7 is available for 2nd gen only.
Thank you